# Spring boot JDBC with password lease/renew (as in Vault)

Tags: spring-boot, spring-jdbc

Hashicorp's [Vault](https://www.vaultproject.io/docs/secrets/postgresql/index.html) can be set up to provide database passwords on demand; each password can be used for a certain "lease" period (say 1 hour) before being renewed, and a maximum use period can be set after which the password has to be trashed and a new one obtained.

In Spring Boot, the JDBC connection is configured at application start, and it is assumed that the JDBC password is coded in the application.properties file (or, alternatively, obtained at application bootstrap time via Spring Cloud Config or equivalent) and used forever.

QUESTION: How might I implement a way in Spring Boot to reset the JDBC password by accessing Vault when a connection attempt fails due to an expired password?

Is there a way to set some sort of handler gets invoked when the connection fails due to an old password, and resets it to a new value?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out this open source project available on GitHub; I think it might just be what you are looking for. Note: From the looks of it, this is currently a Spring Cloud Incubator project (has the potential of becoming an official Spring endorsed open source library in the future), and there are only three contributors. You would have to see if it is "reliable enough" to suit your needs.

https://github.com/spring-cloud-incubator/spring-cloud-vault-config

--- Here's a quick summary of useful information ---

Add the following dependency to pom.xml:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-cloud-vault-starter-config</artifactId>
    <version>x.y.z</version>
</dependency>
```

Create a standard Spring Boot application - provided example is just a main application class:

```
@SpringBootApplication
@RestController
public class Application {

    @RequestMapping("/")
    public String home() {
        return "Hello World!";
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }

}
```

> When it runs it will pick up the external configuration from the
>   default local Vault server on port 8200 if it is running. To modify
>   the startup behavior you can change the location of the Vault server
>   using bootstrap.properties (like application.properties but for the
>   bootstrap phase of an application context), e.g.

bootstrap.yml:

```
spring.cloud.vault:
    host: localhost
    port: 8200
    scheme: http
    connection-timeout: 5000
    read-timeout: 15000
```

`host` sets the hostname of the Vault host. The host name will be used for SSL certificate validation

`port` sets the Vault port

`scheme` setting the scheme to http will use plain HTTP. Supported schemes are http and https.

`connection-timeout` sets the connection timeout in milliseconds

`read-timeout` sets the read timeout in milliseconds

Comment: This project allows one to store the Spring Boot configuration in Vault securely, but it does not appear to address at all the password lease/renew functionality.

Comment: There's no renew functionality in yet. Refreshing static secrets is not a big deal but refreshing database/service secrets is an issue. Databases handle user changes in different ways. MySQL does not care if you delete a user once a connection was established while a DB2 database freaks out. I think updating the data source/pool is feasible. You should remain on the safe side by dealing with expiry by restarting your service once in a while. We have carefully to investigate how to use the expiry/renew feature in a way without breaking your app, therefore we did not add support for it yet.